# PHP: How to hide URL

Tags: php, download

I have the following `download.php` script to download a file, which works great:

```
<?php

header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");

$file = $_GET["file"];
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=" . urlencode($file));   
header("Content-Type: application/force-download");
header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
header("Content-Type: application/download");
header("Content-Description: File Transfer");            
header("Content-Length: " . filesize($file));
flush(); 
$fp = fopen($file, "r");
while (!feof($fp))
{
    echo fread($fp, 65536);
    flush(); 
} 
fclose($fp);

?>
```

What I want to achieve is to hide the URL where this file is located, so that when the user clicks a link such as `<a target="_blank" href="http://domain.com/files/download.php?file=filename.pdf">Download file</a>`, a new tab opens up with no URL and starts downloding the file. What is actually happening is the new tab opens and the file download starts but the URL bar is displaying `http://domain.com/files/download.php?file=filename.pdf`.

If this cannot be done with php, how can I achieve this? I have seen several downloads where the URL is not shown, so I know this is somehow possible.

EDIT: Here is the reason I want to do this: We will send a html mailing with a link to the file download, and the website where this file download is hosted is not the website from the company which sends the mail.

As always, thank you very much.

Comment: Most browsers don't allow for this. And people can still inspect the element. Your best option would be to store the filename in the database and link to the id like this: `http://domain.com/files/download.php?id=123` then query the database get the file from there. People wont see the file name then.

Comment: And/or post the filename to download.php instead of sending it as a query string param. Adding a user token and requiring it on the PHP side will require users are logged in to download.

Comment: In addition to @GetOffMyLawn you could implement a maximum number of times (say three) this particular link is allowed to be downloaded.

Comment: @GetOffMyLawn I want the people not to see(in the URL bar) the domain where it is being downloaded from. If they really want to know they can inspect and it is ok, I just want to hide it for most common users.

Comment: Could could use `mod_proxy` to somewhat hide it. This is not specific to PHP.

Answer (score 2):

A typical way doing this, is to place the files you want to provide for download outside your docroot.
Your download script should know about this place and has to process the requested filename considering this.

For example:

`path/in/your/system/docroot/download.php`
and
`path/in/your/system/files/filename.pdf`

If someone is requesting  `download.php?file=filename.pdf` your script has to look up in `path/in/your/system/files/` for this file and has to handle it.

Answer (score 0):

In the end, it's not possible because the user can open Google Inspector and check the Network tab.

Edit: If that's the case, you would use JavaScript:

Edit 2: In case the popup is blocked by the browser or addon, use a fallback:

Edit 3: In case JS is disabled:

```
<head><meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5;http://domain.com/files/download.php?file=filename.pdf"> 
    <script>
     var win = window.open("http://domain.com/files/download.php?file=filename.pdf");
      if (!win) {
               window.location = "http://domain.com/files/download.php?file=filename.pdf";      
      }
    </script>
  </head>
```

Edit 4: If you don't want the user to see the domain of the user site at all, get your PHP script to download the file and then output that to the user:

```
header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");

$file = $_GET["file"];
$file = 'http://otherdomain.com/location/' . $file; // This line should suffice for all that you're trying to do
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=" . urlencode($file));   
header("Content-Type: application/force-download");
header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
header("Content-Type: application/download");
header("Content-Description: File Transfer");            
header("Content-Length: " . filesize($file));
flush(); 
$fp = fopen($file, "r");
while (!feof($fp))
{
    echo fread($fp, 65536);
    flush(); 
} 
fclose($fp);
```

Comment: I know, but a regular user will not do so. He will just download the file and close the tab.

Comment: @pablito.aven if that's the case, use JavaScript to open a new window to point to your file download script.

Comment: The link is within a mailing, so I can't open the link with Javascript. Can I use javascript to hide the current url address instead of opening a new window with hidden url address?

Comment: You can point the email link to a PHP script that outputs that JavaScript.

Comment: So your email would point to: LinkProvider.php which outputs the above JavaScript which then points to your download script.

Comment: But then, if the user has javascript disabled, the download will never start. If the user has javascript disabled (1% of users) I don't mind the url showing up.

Comment: The above edit should work. The meta tag provided will redirect to the PDF after 5 seconds (which is more than enough time for your JS to load if JS is enabled).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93710/discussion-between-pablito-aven-and-ajacian81).

Comment: "In the end, it's not possible" - this is just plain wrong. You can easily proxy the file's content via readfile(). See http://php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php#refsect1-function.readfile-examples

Comment: @aeno Yes we talked about this in chat. He wanted to be able to have the user download a file from email and open in a new tab without any address being shown. I said this was not possible. If you look at Edit 4 it provides a mechanism to proxy the content.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new window with iframe content to that URL.

```
var win = window.open("", "Title", "toolbar=no, location=no, directories=no, status=no, menubar=no, scrollbars=yes, resizable=yes, width=780, height=200, top="+(screen.height-400)+", left="+(screen.width-840));
win.document.body.innerHTML = "<iframe src='YOUR URL'></iframe>";
```

Answer (score 0):

If you remove the `target="_blank"` no new tab will be opened and the file will just be downloaded.

Answer (score 0):

Submit the form as POST and use $_REQUEST to get the file:

```
$file = $_REQUEST["file"];
```